# How to reverse a linkedlist recursively in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to reverse `linkedlist` recursively in `Javascript`. I have tried myself and search the net to find it. But no success. Below is the code I tried:

```
var Node = (function(){
    function Node(val){
        this.elem = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
    return Node;
})();

var SLinkedlist = (function(){
    function SLinkedlist(){
        this.head = new Node("head");
    }
    return SLinkedlist;
})();

SLinkedlist.prototype.find = function(val){
    var current = this.head;
    while(current !== null && current.elem !== val){
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current;
}

SLinkedlist.prototype.insert = function(newVal, val){
    var current = this.find(val);
    var newNode = new Node(newVal);
    newNode.next = current.next;
    current.next = newNode;
}
function reverseLinkedList(list, previous){

      //We need to use the the current setting of
      //list.next before we change it. We could save it in a temp variable,
      //or, we could call reverseLinkedList recursively
      console.log(list);
      if(list !== null && list.next !==null){
        reverseLinkedList(list.next, list);
      }
      console.log("after recursion!")
      console.log(list);      
      //Everything after 'list' is now reversed, so we don't need list.next anymore.
      //We passed previous in as an argument, so we can go ahead and set next to that.
      list.next = previous;
     }
reverseLinkedList(list.head, null);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any code to show your progress?

Comment: yes! Updated my question with code. Recursive method is taken from some example.

Comment: @Arpit- thanks for formatting it. I am new here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is similar to this:

```
var list = 
{
  name: "1",
  next: {
    name: "2",
    next: {
      name: "3",
      next: {
        name: "4"
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log("Original list");
var head = list;
while (head != undefined) {
  console.log(head.name);
  head = head.next;
}
```

which renders

```
Original list 
1 
2 
3 
4
```

You can reverse it with a recursive function like so:

```
head = reverse(list, undefined);

console.log("Reverse list");
while (head != undefined) {
  console.log(head.name);
  head = head.next;
}


function reverse(list, prev) {
  // if this is the last node, switch it with previous and return
  if (list.next == undefined) {
    list.next = prev;
    return list;
  }

  // otherwise, switch it with the reverse of what is next
  var ret = reverse(list.next, list);
  list.next = prev;
  return ret;
}
```

which renders

```
Reverse list 
4 
3 
2 
1
```

How does it work? It's based on the principle that:

```
Reverse([1 2 3 4]) ==   
[ Reverse([2 3 4]) 1 ] ==  
[ Reverse([3 4]) 2 1 ] ==  
[ 4 3 2 1 ]
```

Comment: @sklivvz- thanks a lot for you solution. I understood the concept behind it, but i was having problem to incorporate recursion into my current linkedlist structure. my linked list first node is "head" which is pointing to the first data. eg:       var list = 
{
  name: "head",
  next: {
    name: "1",
    next: {
      name: "2",
      next: {
        name: "3"
      }
    }
  }
};

Comment: @sklivvz- could you please let me know if I should have "head" node as my first element in the link? Thanks!

Comment: @alps07 if you want "head" to be at the tail, you can use the same, otherwise, reverse `list.next` :-). Experiment! Normally I wouldn't use a "head" element.

Comment: @slivvz- I have not seen any where singlylinkedlist has tail pointer. I have achieve to recursively reverse the linked list with my datastructure. but down side is that I am creating global variable which is a new instance of linkedlist to store reversed list. My returned list has last element as "head" node. I will try again. Your solution is much cleaner and simple to understand. I am new to javascript trying to learn  it with solving data-structure algorithm. javascript scoping makes thing little tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my object-oriented recursive solution.

```
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
}

function SLinkedList(node) {
    if (node) {
        this.head = node;
    } else {
        this.head = null;
    }
}

SLinkedList.prototype.prepend = function(node) {
    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node;
}

SLinkedList.prototype.print = function() {
    var arr = [];
    var current = this.head;
    while (current !== null) {
        arr.push(current.value);
        current = current.next;
    }
    alert(arr.join(' '));
}

SLinkedList.prototype.reverse = function() {
    if (this.head === null || this.head.next === null) {
        return;
    }
    var first = this.head;
    var rest = new SLinkedList(this.head.next);
    rest.reverse();
    first.next.next = first;
    first.next = null;
    this.head = rest.head;
}

var list = new SLinkedList();
list.prepend(new Node(4));
list.prepend(new Node(3));
list.prepend(new Node(2));
list.prepend(new Node(1));
list.print();

list.reverse();
list.print();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5c9gtstk/1/

A few tips for your code, that aren't 100% wrong but I think will help, mostly for brushing up on your linked list:

- it's not typical to have a first node with "head" as the value, though you can do it - just start with your "head" node's `next`.
- the `console.log(list)` lines don't tell too much about what's happening because the data structure only contains an `elem` and `next`, which is why I wrote a print function. That can help you debug.
- your insert function is also atypical but that's not really an issue in this algorithm :)

http://www.thatjsdude.com/interview/linkedList.html#singlyLinkedList has a simple, concise explanation of how you can do it.

As for your reverse algorithm, you almost have the correct idea. The main tip I can give here is to draw out what's happening in your recursive calls! Execute your code step-by-step by hand, slowly. It'll take a few seconds but make everything 100% clear.

Specifically, is `list.next = previous;` all you need to do after reversing the rest of the list? There are a few other pointers you'll need to change.

Others, including an answer here, have given a better explanation than I can give. Again, diagrams are key. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/ has a good, short explanation - skip to the part about the recursive method.

The 2 links I have above are 1 browser page each. I encourage you to take a look.

Comment: @bbill- Thank you very much for the recursive solution. I need to change my Singlylinkedlist constructor as you have it here.

Comment: Sure. Your code's very close, you're just missing a few details. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Also, no, you don't have to change your constructor, actually. Since your reverse method acts on nodes.

Comment: @bbill-Thanks bbill for your detail explanation. I appreciate that you gave time to explain it. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a linked list, we can use simple recursion method. Pass the head of linked list to the below method.

```
reverse( head ) {
    if( head ) {
        reverse( head.next );
        console.log( head.data );
    }
}
```

Complete working solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/o1xbd5ge/1/)

Comment: This solution is not reversing of the linked list. Its just prints the linked list in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answers, here's a LIFO (last in, first out) linked list implementation in ES6/JavaScript, with a function to reverse the list both recursively and *in-place* (without creating a new List):

```js
class Element {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class List {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.head = null;
    if (arr) {
      arr.forEach(el => this.add(new Element(el)));
    }
  }

  get length() {
    return this.head ? this.countElements(1, this.head) : 0;
  }

  add(el) {
    const element = el;
    element.next = this.head;
    this.head = element;
  }

  countElements(count, element) {
    return element.next ? this.countElements(count + 1, element.next) : count;
  }

  toArray(arr = [], element = this.head) {
    arr.push(element.value);
    return element && element.next ? this.toArray(arr, element.next) : arr;
  }
  
  reverse(prev = null) {
    if (this.head.next) {
      const current = this.head;
      this.head = this.head.next;
      current.next = prev;
      return this.reverse(current);
    }
    this.head.next = prev;
    return this;
  }
}

const list = new List([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8 ,9 , 10]);
console.log(list.toArray().toString());  // returns LIFO list as array (last list el = first array el)
console.log(list.reverse().toArray().toString()); // returns LIFO list reversed as array(first first)
```

Comment: IMHO this one is the best and easy to understand solution.

Answer (score 0):

These two existing answers offer great solutions to the problem, but I thought it might be helpful to know why your code isn't working.  In javascript, when a recursive call executes, a new closure is created with its own scope.  So in the final call, the one where the "tail" is located, the `list` variable that refers to it is actually a local variable which has overwritten the existing `list` in the environment.  Consequently, when the function exits, reference to this local `list` is lost if it is not returned.

What the other two answers do is to return that value and store it in a temp variable (the comments in your code are actually not helpful.. you need to store the tail somewhere or you will lose it!)

As you may know, you are not polluting the global scope if all this is handled inside your reverse function.

Also @bbill is absolutely right about executing the code by hand, one step at a time in something like Chrome devtools.  This can really offer great insight into what's happening.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:
I took reference from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYH83T4q6Vs
Basically, once we reach last node recursively, we then change the pointer from the last node to point it to the prev node.

```
class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    reverseLLRec(node) {
        if (!node.next) {
            this.head = node;
            return;
        }
        this.reverseLLRec(node.next);
        const curr = node.next;
        curr.next = node;
        node.next = null;
    }
}
```

```js
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    reverseLLRec(node) {
        if (!node.next) {
            this.head = node;
            return;
        }
        this.reverseLLRec(node.next);
        const curr = node.next;
        curr.next = node;
        node.next = null;
    }

    insertAtLast(data) {
        const node = new Node(data);
        if (this.head === null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            let current = this.head;
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node;
        }
    }

    printList() {
        let curr = this.head;
        let list = [];
        while (curr) {
            list.push(curr.val);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        console.log(list);
    }
}

const ll = new LinkedList();
ll.insertAtLast(1);
ll.insertAtLast(2);
ll.insertAtLast(3);
ll.insertAtLast(4);
ll.insertAtLast(5);
console.log('Before reverse:');
ll.printList();
ll.reverseLLRec(ll.head);
console.log('After reverse:');
ll.printList();
```